# I have to write a script that receives 5 numbers from the promt and push them in the array, and thwn to display the max number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So i have this written so far, but i do not really know what i am doing wrong, cause my maxNum will alert undefined.

```js
function fiveNum() {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let ranNum = prompt("Enter number!");
    arrNum.push(ranNum);
  }
  let maxNum;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let maxNum = arrNum[0];
    if (maxNum > arrNum[i])
      maxNum = arrNum[i]
  }
  alert("You`re highest number is " + maxNum);
}
fiveNum()
```

Comment: You need to call `parseInt()` on the input. Otherwise you're comparing them as strings, not numbers.

Comment: Each time through the loop you're resetting `maxNum` to `arrNum[0]`. That should be before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.max` method, it should convert strings to numbers under the hood.`Math.max` doesn't accept array as argument, so the spread operator `...` passes all elements of `arrNum` as individual arguments. Quoting the ECMA Specification for `Math.max`:

> ```
> Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.
> ```

```js
function fiveNum() {
  const arrNum = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let n = prompt("Enter number!");
    arrNum.push(n);
  }
  let maxNum = Math.max(...arrNum);
  alert("Your highest number is " + maxNum);
}
fiveNum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `let maxNum = arrNum[0]` out of the loop. There are two problems with this:

1. The `let` declaration makes the scope local to the loop body, so it doesn't update the variable declared before the loop.
2. You reset it to the first element of the array each time, so you're not comparing with the previous maximum.

You also need to convert the input to a number, otherwise you'll compare them as strings. `"10" < "2"`.

And your comparison `maxNum > arrNum[i]` is wrong. It should be `<`.

```js
function fiveNum() {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let ranNum = prompt("Enter number!");
    arrNum.push(Number(ranNum));
  }
  let maxNum = arrNum[0];
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    if (maxNum < arrNum[i])
      maxNum = arrNum[i]
  }
  alert("You`re highest number is " + maxNum);
}
fiveNum()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The variable `i` used in both for loops is not declared with the let or const keyword. This can cause the variable to be declared in the `global scope`, which can lead to unintended behavior. To fix this, declare the variable `i` with the `let` keyword in both loops, like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // code here
}
```

1. In the second loop where you are trying to find the maximum number, you are declaring a new variable `maxNum` inside the loop. This creates a new variable with the same name as the outer `maxNum` variable, and the outer variable is not updated. To fix this, remove the `let` keyword before `maxNum` inside the loop, like this:

```
let maxNum = arrNum[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (maxNum < arrNum[i]) {
      maxNum = arrNum[i];
    }
  }
```

Your code should look like this:

```
function fiveNum() {
  const arrNum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let ranNum = prompt("Enter number!");
    arrNum.push(ranNum);
  }
  let maxNum = arrNum[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (maxNum < arrNum[i]) {
      maxNum = arrNum[i];
    }
  }
  alert("Your highest number is " + maxNum);
}
fiveNum(); // this should now work
```

I hope it helps.